# slim framework method not allowed exception handling with middleware

Tags: php, exception, request, slim

I'm making an api on slim framework and i have some routes like

```
$app->group('/api', function() use ($app){

    $app->post('/login', '\App\Controllers\Api\Auth\AuthController:postSignIn');

    $app->post('/register', '\App\Controllers\Api\Auth\RegisterController:postRegister');

});
```

and if i use get request for any links i got this "method not allowed" exception.

I want to handle this exception in middleware . is it possible and if how can i do ?

I want to learn write and use middleware.

please help me ...

Comment: What do you mean by saying "handle this exception in middleware"? What do you want to do exactly? What is the relation of the middleware and this `method not allowed` exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can  add a middellare function for this route like this function

```
$GetHandeler=function($req,$res,$next){
if($res->isGet()){

return $res->getBody()->write("Get Method not allowed");
}
if($res->isPost())
$res=$next($req,$res);
return $res; 
};
```

After that you can add this function to your route like this

```
$app->group('/api', function() use ($app){

    $app->post('/login', '\App\Controllers\Api\Auth\AuthController:postSignIn');

    $app->post('/register', '\App\Controllers\Api\Auth\RegisterController:postRegister');

})->add($GetHandeler);
```